# Villagers sitting on the bench?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I heard they do it behind your back but some players got lucky and caught them sitting on the bench/benches during the day. Is there a certain time for it or it's at random?

Comment: It's just random. I only see my uchi characters sit on the bench though... Maybe it's just a strange coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's random. I saw Deidre sitting on the bench during the meteor shower last night.

Answer (score 0):

It is random. I saw **Fuchsia** sitting on the *yellow bench* and she asked me to sit with her.

Answer (score -2):

There is no certain time, it is completely random. Sometimes they will be asleep on the bench, as I have seen in my town.